# mysql optimizing queries with better values

Tags: mysql, optimization

I just find so many queries status of "Copying to tmp table" in process list, these queries are running above 40 seconds.

Server details:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log
my.cnf values:
key_buffer_size = 134217728
query_cache_limit = 2097152;
max_heap_table_size = 536870912;
tmp_table_size = 536870912;
concurrent_insert     AUTO
low_priority_updates     OFF
table_open_cache = 12288;
long_query_time = 2;
max_connections        = 300
join_buffer_size=1048576
interactive_timeout=300
wait_timeout=300
innodb_buffer_pool_size =2G;
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = OFF
```

result of "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'qc%'":

```
Qcache_free_blocks     12334    
Qcache_free_memory     42059504
Qcache_hits     330467210
Qcache_inserts     946786273
Qcache_lowmem_prunes     2815011
Qcache_not_cached     177691822
Qcache_queries_in_cache     21886
Qcache_total_blocks     56201
```

Please suggest better values.

Please let me know if any thing required

(from comments)

```
SELECT  myid,inb_id,message,date,STATUS
    FROM  messages
    WHERE  youid =userid
      AND  STATUS =3
    GROUP BY  myid
    ORDER BY  date DESC
    LIMIT  0 , 15

CREATE TABLE messages (
    myid int(10) NOT NULL, 
    youid int(10) NOT NULL, 
    message text NOT NULL, 
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    inb_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    readed varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    status int(10) NOT NULL, 
    delete int(11) NOT NULL, 
    today varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    dupdate varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (inb_id), 
    KEY Idxdate (date), 
    KEY Idxyouid (youid), 
    KEY Idxdupdate (dupdate), 
    KEY Idxid (myid), 
    KEY Idxmyid (myid,youid), 
    KEY Idxyouread (youid,readed), 
    KEY Idxyouid_status (youid,status), 
    KEY Idxyoudt (youid,status,date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=165893279 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Consider reading some stuff on tmp tables: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/19/tmp_table_size-and-max_heap_table_size/

Comment: Consider using ramdisk to speed things up..

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time using `Copying to tmp table` as a way to diagnose slow queries. These `tmp tables` aren't really tables. They are memory structures (that can spill to disk if need be). A great many queries, especially aggregage (`GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`) queries must do this to get their results.

If you have slow queries look at them one by one. Use `EXPLAIN` on them. Figure out whether you need new indexes.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/  is a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not useful without also having `Uptime`, RAM size, `query_cache_size`.

- `table_open_cache` is terribly high; I hope you don't have thousands of tables?
- `tmp_table_size = 536870912` is dangerously high!  It should not be more than about 1% of RAM.  It is allocated for each tmp table in each query.  So, a big value threatens to blow out RAM, leading to swapping, which is terrrrrible for performance.

In order to further diagnose your problem, please provide

- the SELECT,
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`,
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

And no, you probably cannot "tune your way out of a performance problem".

**More**

- Lower `table_open_cache` to 200
- Lower `query_cache_size` to 50M

**More more**

```
    KEY Idxyouid        (youid), 
    KEY Idxyouid_status (youid,status), 
    KEY Idxyoudt        (youid,status,date)
```

In a pattern like this, keep the longest one, `DROP` the others.

Here's what is probably going on:

- `INDEX(youid, status)` is being used to find about 2778 rows.
- Those rows are scattered around the table.
- The table is too big to be cached in RAM.
- The `SELECT` is fetching a `TEXT` column; text columns, at least if they are big, are stored "off-record".  That means an extra disk I/O to get the value.
- 2778 I/Os on HDD takes about 27.78 seconds (a crude Rule of Thumb is 100 IOPs).
- 27.78 is close enough to the measured 40 for me to declare that I have deduced the problem.
- (Note that "copying to tmp table" gave no *useful* clue.)

I am puzzled...

Can `youid` send multiple `messages` to `myid`?  You *cannot* `ORDER BY date` at the same time you `GROUP BY myid`; you will get a random date!  Since I don't understand your query, I can only throw some random ideas your direction...

The combination `youid, myid, date` is not unique, correct?

So, what is the solution?

- Do you need the `message`?  (Leaving out that column *might* eliminate most of the I/O.)
- If you do need `message`, grab it later.  (More on that, below.)
- If you typically fetch multiple rows based on `youid`, then this technique can be quite effective:

Replace

```
PRIMARY KEY(inb_id),
INDEX(youid)
```

with

```
PRIMARY KEY(youid, date, inb_id)  -- to better cluster the rows
INDEX(inb_id)  -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

If `myid` is the common way to fetch rows, then start the PK with `myid` instead of `youid`.

(No the new PK is not perfect, but it provides some benefit.)

**Grab `message` later**

Assuming that I have correctly identified that fetching `message` is the costly part, and noting that you want only 15 messages, let's reformulate the query to fetch only 15, not all 2778.

I can't figure how to make the `GROUP BY myid` make sense, so I removed it.

```
SELECT  m2.myid, m2.inb_id, m2.message, m2.date, m2.STATUS
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  inb_id
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  youid = 1234
              AND  STATUS = 3
            ORDER BY  date DESC
            LIMIT  0, 15 
        ) AS m1
    JOIN  messages AS m2  USING(inb_id)
```

The "secret sauce" in this formulation is that it discovers 15 inb_ids in the "derived table" (ie, subquery), then looks up only those 15 for the sluggish process of finding `message`.  Total time should be about 0.2 seconds.  And your existing `KEY Idxyoudt (youid,status,date)` is optimal for it.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the reply

Uptime:  6232200

Ram Size:  4GB

Tables: 100

Comment: Query:

SELECT myid,inb_id,message,date,STATUS FROM messages WHERE youid =userid AND STATUS =3 GROUP BY myid ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0 , 15


Explain:

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra


1  SIMPLE  messages  ref  Idxyouidstatus  Idxyouidstatus  8  const,const  2778  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: query_cache_size = 268435456;

Comment: (added more); Is `userid` a constant; where does it come from?

Comment: About how many rows in `messages`?  Do you get back about 2778 rows from the query?

Comment: userid is auto increment id from users table. Its was when user login stored in session

Comment: in messages 2 crores rows. Here I am given 15 limit, but searching all 2778 rows of that user based on query

Comment: But the query is not using the `users` table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages`; I have another thought -- about datatypes.  Also, what type of disk - HDD or SSD?

Comment: What do you do with 2778 rows when you get them?  (I am thinking the solution is to avoid getting stuff you won't use.)

Comment: query not using users table, I only get the userid from users tables when I loggedin site.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `messages` (  `myid` int(10) NOT NULL,  `youid` int(10) NOT NULL,  `message` text NOT NULL,  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  `inb_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `readed` varchar(30) NOT NULL,  `status` int(10) NOT NULL,  `delete` int(11) NOT NULL,  `today` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  `dupdate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`inb_id`),  KEY `Idxdate` (`date`),  KEY `Idxyouid` (`youid`),  KEY `Idxdupdate` (`dupdate`),  KEY `Idxid` (`myid`),  KEY `Idxmyid` (`myid`,`youid`),  KEY `Idxyouread` (`youid`,`readed`),  KEY `Idxyouid_status` (`youid`,`status`),  KEY `Idxyoudt` (`youid`,`status`,`date`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=165893279 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: disk type is:  HDD

Comment: I am getting 15 rows on first load, then usrs scroll down loading next 15 messages.